# Picture Addings

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to have a picture all at the bottom of one of the screens of my app, I finally achieved this, but eclipse automatically adds a bar on the top and at the bottom of my picture. I don't want this to be, could you please help?
If you need any more information from me, please say :P.

Edit: activity_main.xml:

`

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/metro" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/syllabus" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bus" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="175dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/supermarkt" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/restaurants" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/geldautomaat" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/kaartrome" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/italiaans" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/telefoon" />

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Skyline"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/skyline" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Comment: If you post the code you have now it will be easier to help.

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's happening if you don't have your relevant code posted.

If you're using an ImageView and writing your layout in XML the code should look something like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ...other views for the screen...

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_heigth="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/some_img" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Assuming you're using a LinearLayout with vertical orientation, this should add your image to the layout, make it exactly the width of it's parent (the screen if it's parent is the root layout), and scale the length appropriately. The `gravity` makes the picture drop to the bottom of the layout (unless something is laid out under it).

There should be no bars at all.

EDIT: Code is now posted.
You should have all the views in your XML part of a root view, like the RelativeLayout that your image at the bottom is in. If you move the head of the relative layout to the top of the XML and add the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to it, the image should do exactly what you want. The header should look like this and be at the top of the XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Have you gone through the [android developer tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)? They are extremely helpful.

Comment: I actually meant, when it doesnt only show the picture but also a stripe at the top of it and one at the bottom, do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Are you sure those aren't just editor lines to resize the image or indicate its alignment? Are you using pure eclipse or the eclipse that is packaged with the Android SDK package?

Comment: I am using packaged eclipse and I don't think it are editorlines as I can make them black by changing background at properties to #000000.

Comment: Try adjusting the XML like I've stated. If it's still an issue, then it could be somewhere in the java code. If you mean the background of the RelativeLayout changes the bars, then it's probably just padding around the image. But if you make the RelativeLayout the root layout, then it should fix that.

Comment: Yes you're right it is padding, can you help me with what you suggested?

Comment: I'm not sure what you still need help with. I've given you the code and told you where to put it. Why don't you do the tutorials, especially the section on Layouts. If you still have questions then, it will be easier for you to specifically ask what you want.